# Checkbox enable/disable not working in IE

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to enable/disable a checkbox 'cb1Sub' when another checkbox 'cb1' is checked/unchecked.

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <asp:CheckBox ID="cb1" runat="server" onchange="checkedCB1(this);" />
  </td>
  <td>
   <asp:CheckBox ID="cb1Sub" runat="server" Enabled="false" />
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>




function checkedCB1(elm) {
        var elmId = $(elm).find("input").attr('id');
        var elmChk = $(elm).find("input").attr('checked');
        var elmSubId = elmId + "Sub";

        if (elmChk == "checked") {
            document.getElementById(elmSubId).disabled = false;
        } else {
            document.getElementById(elmSubId).disabled = true;
        }
    }
```

This works in firefox, but not in IE.

I think when I enable the checkbox, its span is still disabled.

From firebug, I'm seeing this:

```
<span disabled="disabled">
<input type="checkbox" name="cb1Sub" id="cb1Sub">
</span>
```

Comment: Try `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

Comment: `$(elm).find("input")` ? `elem` itself is the `input`

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkedCB1(elm) {
        var elmId = $(elm).find("input").attr('id');
        //use property instead of attr
        **var elmChk = $(elm).find("input").prop('checked');**
        var elmSubId = elmId + "Sub";

        if (elmChk == "checked") {
            document.getElementById(elmSubId).disabled = false;
        } else {
            document.getElementById(elmSubId).disabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Problem is not with 'elmChk'. If I use attr, value of elmChk will be "checked". If I use prop, elmChk will be true/false.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, more a response to some inefficient code.

```
var elmId = $(elm).find("input").attr('id');
```

is hugely more efficient as:

```
var elmId = elm.id;
```

The *checked* property is boolean, it's true or false so

```
 if (elmChk == "checked") {
```

should just be:

```
 if (elmChk) {
```

Anyway, presuming that you want *cb1Sub* to be enabled when *cb1* is checked, then:

```
function checkedCB1(elm) {
    document.getElementById(elm.id + "Sub").disabled = !elm.checked;
}
```